# C++ template ambiguous overload, single function

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, c++-templates

While trying to wrap my head around templates, I quickly ran into, what seems to be an incongruous mess of standards and it's implementation quirks between gcc and clang.

Without further ado, here's my very simple template function that implements a simple reference based solution to swapping two entities (to keep it simple, I am really only using it with integers):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void swap(T &a, T &b) {
  T temp;

  temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int a,b;

    a = 7, b = 10;

    cout << "a is " << a << " while b is " << b << endl;
    swap(a,b);
    cout << "a is " << a << " while b is " << b << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling with gcc 13, it fails as [follows](https://godbolt.org/z/E368oYM7q):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:21:9: error: call of overloaded 'swap(int&, int&)' is ambiguous
   21 |     swap(a,b);
      |     ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/exception_ptr.h:41,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/exception:164,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/ios:41,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/ostream:40,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/iostream:41,
                 from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/move.h:196:5: note: candidate: 'std::_Require<std::__not_<std::__is_tuple_like<_Tp> >, std::is_move_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_Tp> > std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = int; _Require<__not_<__is_tuple_like<_Tp> >, is_move_constructible<_Tp>, is_move_assignable<_Tp> > = void]'
  196 |     swap(_Tp& __a, _Tp& __b)
      |     ^~~~
<source>:5:6: note: candidate: 'void swap(T&, T&) [with T = int]'
    5 | void swap(T &a, T &b) {
      |      ^~~~
```

On trying with clang, the same [thing](https://godbolt.org/z/E368oYM7q) with a different wording:

```
<source>:21:5: error: call to 'swap' is ambiguous
    swap(a,b);
    ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/bits/move.h:196:5: note: candidate function [with _Tp = int]
    swap(_Tp& __a, _Tp& __b)
    ^
<source>:5:6: note: candidate function [with T = int]
void swap(T &a, T &b) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I just have a single function up there, so why is there ambiguity here? Or does the STL have a swap function already included?

Comment: `std::swap` does exist, avoid `using namespace std;`.

Comment: There is a templated `std::swap()` algorithm in the standard library (in different headers depending on which standard) and the standard does not prevent headers like `<iostream>` from declaring or defining those functions. By having `using namespace std` and declaring your own templated swap, you are risking a name collision, and hence ambiguity.   To avoid that potential, options include (1) include the required standard header and use `std::swap()` without defining your own (2) avoid use of `using namespace std`  or (3) rename your `swap()` to something else  that doesn't clash.

Comment: And, incidentally, unless you are using a compiler and library dating from the mid 1990s, STL is the wrong nomenclature.   The correct terminology since 1998 (when the first C++ standard was ratified) is "C++ standard library".    The STL is an older library that influenced the design of the C++ standard library, but the C++ standard library is not the STL.

Comment: @Peter thanks for the tip! I didn't knew that even supposedly trivial functions like swap are now provided by the "standard library"! Coming from C, I feel C++ is _really_ a different language by and large.